# API testing: Can I reduce my API functional testing effort by increasing my unit tests? Can I replace a functional test for a unit test?

Tags: rest, api, unit-testing, testing, soap

I am trying to optimize my API (both restful and SOAP services) testing effort. I am thinking, one way to do so is by eliminating the redundant functional tests. I am calling them redundant because the same tests might be executed at unit testing level.

I understand that there's developer bias to unit testing so independent functional testing is crucial. I am not trying to replace functional tests by performing extensive unit testing but I am trying to optimize my testing effort by eliminating some of the functional tests while covering them at unit test level.

How can I achieve this? What’s the correlation between unit tests and functional tests?

Let's take an example of customerAccount/add service. Say if I have 6 tests, 2 positive (happy-path) tests, 2 exceeding boundary-value tests, 1 customer not found test, 1 invalid customer test. Can I eliminate one of 2 positive tests and one of 2 'exceeding boundary-value’ tests provided those 2 are tested at unit testing level? So now, 2 tests are covered at unit test level, 4 are at functional testing level.

Developers may not be testing services against the end points, they may test classes and methods instead. But in the above example, we are still testing the end points. So that’s covered.

What do you think of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that having redundant tests should be avoided.  But - what makes tests redundant?  My view is, that a test is redundant if all the potential bugs this test intends to detect are also intended to be found by the remaining tests.

What distinguishes unit-testing, interaction-testing (aka integration-testing), subsystem-testing (aka component-testing or functional-testing) is the respective test goal, which means, which bugs the respective test is intending to catch.

Unit-testing is about catching those bugs that you could find by testing small (even minimally small) isolated pieces of software.  Since unit-testing is the earliest testing step that also has the chance to go deepest into the code, a rule of thumb is that if a bug could be already found by unit-testing, you shold really find it with unit-testing rather than trying to catch that bug in higher level tests.  This seems to be in line with your approach to "eliminating the redundant functional tests" where "the same tests might be executed at unit testing level".  For example, if you aim to find potential bugs in case of an arithmetic overflow within some code, this should exactly be done with unit-testing.  Trying to find the same problem on the level of integration-testing or subsystem-testing would be the wrong approach.

You should be aware, however, that possibly the goal of the subsystem-test (= functional-test if you and me have the same terminology here) was a different one than the similar-looking test on unit-test level.  On subsystem-level you could aim at catching integration bugs, for example if wrong versions of classes are combined (in which case the respective unit-tests of each of the classes might all pass).  Subsystem-tests could also intend to find build-system bugs, like, if generated classes for the environment of your manually written code are not generated as expected.  And so on.

Therefore, before eliminating redundant tests, be sure you have understood the test goals of these tests to be definite about that these tests are truly redundant.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I understand. I need to work towards defining the criteria which makes a test redundant. I think, I should work with developers to define this criteria. Also, this criteria may be subjective. May differ from team to team. At times, developers do not hit api/service end points in their unit tests. At times, developers do not hit the backend i.e., database. They may use an in-memory primitive database for their unit testing. In such case, a component test may not be a replacement for unit testing. But with the help of developers, I should be able to identify some tests as redundant.